[08001][unixODBC]could not translate host name "localhost # Replace with your server's hostname or IP" to address: nodename nor servname provided
On my mac I get error while trying .I tried locahost , 127.0.0.1 and also my ipv4 address
Is there any setting in postgres config.
I am able to connect to postgres using psql -U postgres
Postgres setup is default using brew install on mac
isql -v PostgresDSN

[08001][unixODBC]could not translate host name "localhost  # Replace with your server's hostname or IP" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect

/usr/local/etc/odbc.ini

[PostgresDSN]
Description=PostgreSQL Data Source
Driver=PostgreSQL
Servername=localhost  
Port=5432            
Database=test        
Username=test1      
Password=password 

/usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini

[PostgreSQL]
Description=PostgreSQL ODBC Driver
Driver=/usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so 


pg_hba.conf

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
host    all             all             ::0/0                   trust

postgresql.conf

listen_addresses = '*'  




This psql -U postgres is connecting using UNIX socket not hostname. If you want a true test do  psql -h localhost -U postgres. 2) If the test fails then something in you local network setup is off.


@JorgeCampos, if that where the issue the OP would be getting a could not connect error. The error they are getting is at the network level above Postgres.

psql -h localhost -U postgres ( This works )
psql (14.13 (Homebrew))
Type "help" for help.
postgres=#

added my postgres configs .it is default config using brew install on mac

beware, as you get could not translate host name "localhost  # Replace with your server's hostname or IP" this means that there is some configuration containing the string "localhost  # Replace with your server's hostname or IP", which also means that the "#" is not recognized as comment at that place

So this is a UnixODBC issue. Most likely as @jhole pointed out a configuration error.  Do odbcinst -j to see where UnixODBC  thinks it's conf files are. Best bet is you are picking up one that you have not modified.

This worked !! The comment was not working

new to odbc as I have used jdbc all along. this command helped

What you are saying is you left out the comment in the odbc.ini contents you copied into the question.

the odbc i was editing was incorrect file
